# Asp. Net: MVC authentication throught .Net Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am developing a multi-platform application. I have my asp .net mvc web application and i will develop the ios and android app later. So, i want to manage the user authentication through another project (a .NET Web API project).

And i would like to keep the existing functionality that the [Authorize] attribute offers.

So my question is:

how can I let my MVC project authenticate through the Web Api project, and still maintain the functionality that when a user tries to access a page that needs authentication, he will be redirected to the login page and such

I hope my question is clear enough! If not, don't hesitate to ask some additional questions!

Kind Regards,

Ariel

Comment: Are the Web API and MVC projects going to be hosted on separate domains?

Comment: No, both projects will be hosted on the same domain...